# How to add the values in angular js ng-repeat iteration within html layer?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please find my below code

```
<ul id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list" ng-init="cartArray.total = {}">
    <li class="item odd" ng-if="cartArray.length === 0">No items in your cart..</li>
    <li class="item odd" ng-repeat='y in cartArray'>
        <a href="shopping_cart.html" class="product-image"><img ng-src="" alt="" width="65"></a>
        <div class="product-details">
            <a href="#" title="Remove This Item" class="remove-cart" ng-click="removeFromCart(y)"><i class="pe-7s-trash"></i></a>
            <p class="product-name"><a href="shopping_cart.html">{{y.prodName}}</a> </p>
            <strong>1</strong> x <span class="price" ng-init='cartArray.total.prodAmt = cartArray.total.prodAmt + y.prodAmt'>Rs. {{y.prodAmt}}</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div ng-if="cartArray.length > 0" class="top-subtotal">Subtotal: <span class="price">{{cartArray.total.prodAmt }}</span></div>
```

For example, if array has 2 values 100 and 200, expected output for {{cartArray.total.prodAmt }} is 300(sum) but I'm getting 100200(Concatenated string) as output. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing addition operation please ensure that both variables are in `numeric` type (not in `string`), otherwise it will give concatenated result.

Many options are available for `string` to `numeric` conversion, like:

1. Use `+` before the variable. eg: +`cartArray.total.prodAmt`
2. Use function `Number()`. eg: `Number(cartArray.total.prodAmt)`
3. Use `parse` functions like `Math.parseInt`, `Math.parseFloat` etc. eg: `Math.parseInt(cartArray.total.prodAmt)`
4. Multiply with 1. eg: `cartArray.total.prodAmt * 1`

So change this line `ng-init='cartArray.total.prodAmt = cartArray.total.prodAmt + y.prodAmt'`

**to**

`ng-init='cartArray.total.prodAmt = (+cartArray.total.prodAmt) + (+y.prodAmt)'`

**or**

`ng-init='cartArray.total.prodAmt = Number(cartArray.total.prodAmt) + Number(y.prodAmt)'`

**or**

Use any of the above mentioned methods.

Comment: These all work, but it might also be worth moving the logic inside the controller itself too.  The docs advise against abusing ng-init: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: @Cracker With the above code, when I change the value in quantity textbox,